# Django/MySQL error

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python

I have this error and I'm not sure how to fix it. I looked up some previous questions and some of them say it is because MySQL-python is not installed. However, I do have it installed

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.db import models
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
return import_module('.base', backend_name)
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
      File "/home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: /home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Comment: have you ever try this: `python -c 'import MySQLdb'` ,can it work?

Comment: there is a similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149782/python-mysqldb-problem-wrong-elf-class-elfclass32

Comment: ImportError: /home/bradford/Development/Django/django_1.5.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

I get this when I try your command @the5fire

Comment: Optimal- build version of MySQLdb for you system. Download this from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/  and run command: python setup.py install

Comment: my version is 64 bit not sure if that link you sent me is 32 or 64 =/

Comment: got this error when I tried out your suggestion @nnmware

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/home/bradford/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "/home/bradford/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

Comment: my python is 64 bit! Not sure what bit MySQL-python is but I'm assuming its 32 bit. Doesnt' really say on the download page

Comment: `mysql_config not found` error can be fix by `apt-get install python-mysqldb`,have a try

Comment: If not found mysql-config, then you need install libmysqlclient-dev. If ubuntu- please run : apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

Comment: i dont write then you need install "python-mysqldb", i write- install "libmysqlclient-dev". Read better.